# What's the best way to deal with an unanswerable question?

Tags: discussion

See - [Boolean field: hide (in display) if unchecked](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99279/boolean-field-hide-in-display-if-unchecked)

This question has the caveat of "Without resorting to Views or custom code". I agree with both Clive and Mołot comments and believe that the question is unanswerable in it's current state.

How should this type of question be dealt with? Should it be flagged for deletion (in which case under what category?)? Assuming the user doesn't rewrite the question what should we do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"No" answers are perfectly acceptable, as long as they are correct and they give enough explanation as to why they are the case.